# A view with an equal width as its sibling but with a limit

Tags: android, view

I am trying to build a UI which looks like this :

Underline width is equal to the width of the text when the length of the text is short

```
      Short Text
      __________
```

Underline width is equal to the limit when the length of the text is long

```
  A sample long text
     ____________
```

How can I build a view where the underline width is adaptive in the way described above?

I tried using a `RelativeLayout` which has a `TextView` for text and a empty `TextView` for underline (with `alignLeft` and `alignRight` properties) with a maxWidth property. It looks like the maxWidth property is not honored when `alignLeft` and `alignRight` are set.

Any suggestions to achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the solution. Seems to be working fine.

The idea is to use a `RelativeLayout` with 2 children. Both the child views are `TextViews`. First one behaves like a regular `TextView`. Second one is a `TextView` whose `textColor` is transparent, background is the color that is needed for the underline, `layout_width` is `wrap_content` and `maxWidth` is the limit. Setting same text to both the views seems like doing a reasonably good job.

layout file is like below

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/underline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:maxWidth="160dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/headline"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tags in your xml:

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/underline"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView"
   android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
   android:layout_below="@id/textView"/>
```

The attributes `layout_alignLeft` and `layout_alignRight` will set the view to be aligned to the start and the end of the element you specify. More information about the attributes can be found on [this answer by kcoppock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639732/3131147).

---

EDIT: I see now that you tried this, and it appears maxWidth was ignored. You could try adding padding programatically when you set the text of the TextView, like this:

```
if(textView.getWidth() > maxWidth){
   // Get amount it went over
   int remainingLength = textView.getWidth() - maxWidth;
   // Cut it in half
   int paddingLength = remainingLength / 2
   // Set left/right padding to center the line
   lineView.setPadding(paddingLength, 0, paddingLength, 0);
}
```

Here is the documentation for [setPadding()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).